# Does leaving out my address and employer's address in the cover letter make a bad impression?

Tags: job-search, cover-letter

Frankly, I don't see the point in including addresses. The employer knows their address, and if they need to know mine, it's included elsewhere on the application. It seems like an old-fashioned waste of time. At least, that's my opinion, but I don't know about employers. Would it look bad just to skip to "Dear Hiring Manager"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**There is no downside to using the traditional format. There might be downside to not using it.**

I tend to agree with you that it's an "old-fashioned waste of time".  However, *someone* who looks at your application might care about it.  They might think that you don't understand the expectations, or that you are lazy and didn't take the time to do it "right".  They might think that you don't understand how to do professional communication (and this is, of course, an important part of many jobs you might be applying for).

So, I say just do it.  This is not the place where you want to innovate.

(I'm assuming a printed or separate document cover letter here.  If your cover letter is simply an email, I would not include it, as this isn't the standard for professional email communication).

Answer (score 2):

The address is important in that prospective employers can gauge how local you are. This is even more important in a metro area. For instance, here in Atlanta someone who lives on the north side suburbs is highly unlikely to commute to a south side or far east side job.

You can always put your city if you don't want to put your whole address.

You probably should include everything that's normally in a formal letter and this includes the employer's address. It shows that the letter is targeted and not just a copied letter that's getting sent all over. At least that's the impression. Obviously, they know that you're going to likely send it elsewhere.

As for the salutation, if possible try to get the hiring manager's name. Otherwise it's pretty much just HR spam.  I'm not saying they won't read it but it's less likely it'll be given as much attention as something to a specific person.

We all have to jump through hoops and do things we think are a waste of time. The question you have to ask yourself is it really worth risking annoying someone who is "old school" just so you don't have to type an address or two?

Comment: I think the question is asking about a formal cover letter format, which includes both the recipient's and applicant's name and address. They mention that their address is included elsewhere in the application.

Comment: Good point. I'll clarify